# How to get a particular xml node values using groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, soap, wsdl, soapui

Here is my soap response. I am using free version of soapui.
Someone please help me to get the values 60,61  as an array from **<tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration token="60"> ** node using groovy

```xml
            <tRiseMedia:StreamName>VideoEncoder_Encoder1</tRiseMedia:StreamName>
            <tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration token="61"> 
             <tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>VideoSource_VisibleCamera</tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>           
              </tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration>
         </tRiseMedia:StreamOsdList>
```

Here is my groovy script snippet

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext
def TestCase = context.testCase
PropertiesTestStep = TestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetStreamOSDs').getPropertyValue("response")
def samplexmlreq=new XmlHolder(response)

def tokenFromResponse = samplexmlreq.getNodeValue("/*:OSDConfiguration/@token")


def envelope = new  XmlParser(false, false).parse(samplexmlreq)
def tokens = envelope.'**'.findAll { node -> node.name() == 'tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration' }*.@token
log.info  token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as below

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext
def TestCase = context.testCase
PropertiesTestStep = TestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetStreamOSDs').getPropertyValue("response")

def envelope = new  XmlParser().parseText(response)
//Getting all the token values from the response
def tokens = envelope.'**'.findAll { node -> node.name() == 'tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration' }*.@token
log.info tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you just want a list of the tokens:

```
def xmlText = '''<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <tRiseMedia:GetStreamOSDsResponse>
         <tRiseMedia:StreamOsdList>
            <tRiseMedia:StreamName>VideoEncoder_Encoder1</tRiseMedia:StreamName>
            <tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration token="60"> 
              <tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>VideoSource_VisibleCamera</tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>
               <tt:Type>Text</tt:Type>
               <tt:Position>
                  <tt:Type>Custom</tt:Type>
                  <tt:Pos x="15" y="50"/>
               </tt:Position>
               <tt:TextString>
                  <tt:Type>Sector</tt:Type>                  
               </tt:TextString>
            </tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration>
         </tRiseMedia:StreamOsdList>
         <tRiseMedia:StreamOsdList>
            <tRiseMedia:StreamName>VideoEncoder_Encoder1</tRiseMedia:StreamName>
            <tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration token="61"> 
             <tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>VideoSource_VisibleCamera</tt:VideoSourceConfigurationToken>
               <tt:Type>Text</tt:Type>
               <tt:Position>
                  <tt:Type>Custom</tt:Type>
                  <tt:Pos x="35" y="35"/>
               </tt:Position>
               <tt:TextString>
                  <tt:Type>Sector</tt:Type>                  
               </tt:TextString>
            </tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration>
         </tRiseMedia:StreamOsdList>     
      </tRiseMedia:GetStreamOSDsResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
'''

def envelope = new  XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xmlText)

def tokens = envelope.'**'.findAll { node -> node.name() == 'tRiseMedia:OSDConfiguration' }*.@token

assert tokens == ['60', '61']
```

You can get the response XML like this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def xmlText = new XmlHolder(context.response)
```

In SoapUI you'll use `parse` instead of `parseText`. The `parseText` is for the example because the XML string is in the source as text.

Comment: Gettig error like "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlParser.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder)values: [ ] Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)"

Comment: Try changing `.parseText` to `.parse`. I updated the answer.

Comment: still have the error.

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlParser.parse() is applicable for argument types: (com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder) values: [ ] Possible solutions: parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)

Comment: You will have to update your question with your code.

Comment: updated with the groovy code

Comment: Ok, try with `def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)`

Comment: Thanks for the support, I got the solution without the xmlHolder